# AIC, anova error: Models are not all fitted to the same number of observations, models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset

Tags: r, mixed-model, aic

I have models like this:

```
require(nlme)

set.seed(123)
n <- 100
k <- 5
cat <- as.factor(rep(1:k, n))
cat_i <- 1:k # intercept per kategorie
x <- rep(1:n, each = k)
sigma <- 0.2
alpha <- 0.001
y <- cat_i[cat] + alpha * x + rnorm(n*k, 0, sigma)
plot(x, y)

m1 <- lm(y ~ x)
summary(m1)

m2 <- lm(y ~ cat + x)
summary(m2)

m3 <- lme(y ~ x, random = ~ 1|cat, na.action = na.omit)
summary(m3)
```

Now I am trying to assess whether the random effect should be present in the model. So I compare the models using AIC or anova, and I get the following error:

```
> AIC(m1, m2, m3)
   df       AIC
m1  3 1771.4696
m2  7 -209.1825
m3  4 -154.0245
Warning message:
In AIC.default(m1, m2, m3) :
  models are not all fitted to the same number of observations  
> anova(m2, m3)
Error in anova.lmlist(object, ...) : 
  models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset
```

As you can see, in both cases I use the same dataset. I have found two remedies, but I don't consider them satisfying:

1. [Adding `method = "ML"` to the lme() call](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-March/307348.html) - not sure if it is good idea to change the method.
2. Using `lmer()` instead. Surprisingly, this works, despite the fact that lmer() uses REML method. However I dont like this solution because the `lmer()` doesn't show p-values for coefficients - I like to use older `lme()` instead.

Do you have any idea if this is a bug or not and how can we go around that?

Answer (score 7):

A quick search shows that [it is possible](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/lmm-WITHOUT-random-factor-lme4-td3384054.html) (although I have to admit that I thought it wasn't) and that it isn't a bug...just another case where methods in R are hidden and result in things that seem 'unexpected', but the RTFM crowd say, "It is in the documentation."  Anyway...your solution is to do `anova` with the `lme` as the first argument and the `lm` models as the second (and third if you like) argument(s).  If this seems odd, it is because it is a little odd.  The reason is that when you call `anova`, the `anova.lme` method is called only if the first argument is an `lme` object.  Otherwise, it calls `anova.lm` (which in turn calls `anova.lmlist`; if you dig into `anova.lm`, you'll see why).  For details about how you want to be calling `anova` in this case, pull up help for `anova.lme`.  You'll see that you can compare other models with `lme` models, but they have to be in a position other than the first argument.  Apparently it is also possible to use `anova` on models fit using the `gls` function without caring too much about the order of the model arguments.  But I don't know enough of the details to determine whether that is a good idea or not, or what exactly it implies (it seems probably fine, but your call).  From that link comparing `lm` to `lme` appears to be well documented and cited as a method, so I'd err in that direction, were I you.

Good luck.

Comment: Oh, and user11852's answer in regards to AIC with Gavin's addendum stands, there is no special AIC.lme or anything to address that issue and the whole thing starts to slip beyond my pay grade

Answer (score 4):

This is peculiar definitely. As a first thought: when doing model comparison where models are having different fixed effects structures (`m2` and `m3` for example), it is best to us $ML$ as `REML` will "change" $y$. (It will multiply it with $k$, where $kX= 0$) That is interesting it that it works using `method="ML"` which makes me believe it might not be a bug. It seems almost like it enforces "good practice".

Having said that, let's look under the hood:

```
 methods(AIC)  
 getAnywhere('AIC.default')

 A single object matching ‘AIC.default’ was found
 It was found in the following places
   registered S3 method for AIC from namespace stats
   namespace:stats with value

 function (object, ..., k = 2) 
 {
     ll <- if ("stats4" %in% loadedNamespaces()) 
         stats4:::logLik
     else logLik
     if (!missing(...)) {
         lls <- lapply(list(object, ...), ll)
         vals <- sapply(lls, function(el) {
             no <- attr(el, "nobs") #THIS IS THE ISSUE!
             c(as.numeric(el), attr(el, "df"), if (is.null(no)) NA_integer_ else no)
         })
         val <- data.frame(df = vals[2L, ], ll = vals[1L, ])
         nos <- na.omit(vals[3L, ])
         if (length(nos) && any(nos != nos[1L])) 
             warning("models are not all fitted to the same number of observations")
         val <- data.frame(df = val$df, AIC = -2 * val$ll + k * val$df)
             Call <- match.call()
             Call$k <- NULL
         row.names(val) <- as.character(Call[-1L])
         val
     }
     else {
         lls <- ll(object)
         -2 * as.numeric(lls) + k * attr(lls, "df")
     }     
 }
```

where in your case you can see that :

```
  lls <- lapply(list(m2,m3), stats4::logLik)
  attr(lls[[1]], "nobs")
  #[1] 500
  attr(lls[[2]], "nobs")
  #[1] 498
```

and obviously `logLik` is doing something (maybe?) unexpected...? no, not really, if you look at the documentation of `logLik`, `?logLik`, you'll see it is explicitly stated:

```
 There may be other attributes depending on the method used: see
 the appropriate documentation.  One that is used by several
 methods is ‘"nobs"’, the number of observations used in estimation
 (after the restrictions if ‘REML = TRUE’)
```

which brings us back to our original point, you should be using `ML`.

To use a common saying in CS: *"It's not a bug; it's an (real) feature!"*

**EDIT**:
(Just to address your comment:)
Assume you fit another model using `lmer` this time:

```
m3lmer <- lmer(y ~ x + 1|cat)
```

and you do the following:

```
lls <- lapply(list(m2,m3, m3lmer), stats4::logLik)
attr(lls[[3]], "nobs")
#[1] 500
 attr(lls[[2]], "nobs")
#[1] 498
```

Which seems like a clear discrepancy between the two but it really isn't as Gavin explained. 
Just to state the obvious:

```
 attr( logLik(lme(y ~ x, random = ~ 1|cat, na.action = na.omit, method="ML")),
 "nobs")
#[1] 500
```

There is a good reason why this happens in terms of methodology I think. `lme` does try to make sense of the LME regression for you while `lmer` when doing model comparisons it falls back immediately to it's ML results.
I think there are no bugs on this matter in `lme` and `lmer` just different rationales behind each package.

See also Gavin Simposon's comment on a more insightful explanation of what went on with `anova()` (The same thing practically happens with `AIC`)

Comment: *"you should be using ML" - but how can you explain that `lmer` is using REML (see the model summary) and works fine in AIC? So there are two possibilities: 1) the error message is *a feature*, not bug, and the fact that it works for `lmer` is a bug. Or 2) the error message is *a bug*, not feature.

Comment: See updated post (I had to include some code). I had notice your valid point myself when writing your original response but I originally opted to keep it out so the rationale behind my answer is strictly computation-based.

Comment: @Tomas `lmer()` *doesn't* use REML when you ask it do comparisons. IIRC they included some fancy sugar in `lmer()` so you didn't have to refit the model with `ML` just to compare fits when you want `REML` on individual fits to get best estimates of the variance parameters. Look at `?lmer`, run the first LME example up to and including the `anova(fm1, fm2)` call. Look at the log likelihoods reported by `anova()` and those reported earlier in the printed output. The `anova()` is getting ML estimates for you.

Comment: Good point Gavin, I forget that `lmer` got both at the same time (it uses PLS so it goes around estimating only one at the time). I forgot to the check what you mentioned.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: Does that same special sugar apply when AIC is called rather than ANOVA?

Comment: @rpierce: The AIC reported *within `anova()`* is the one based on ML. The AIC reported just `AIC()` is the one based on REML.